# Summing the results of an array multiplication

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to sum up the result of the multiplication of these two arrays:

```
              Item

Store   0   1   2   3    4
 0      25  64  23  45  14
 1      12  82  19  34  63
 2      54  22  17  32  35

Item     Cost Per Item
   0           $12.00
   1           $17.95
   2           $95.00
   3           $86.50
   4           $78.00
```

I have to sum up the results of the first row, second row, and the third row and display them separately and then add them up. The code that i'm using for the program is the following:

```
import java.util.*;
public class asd
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double items[][]= new double[3][5];
        double cost[]=new double[5];
        loadArray(items, cost);
        System.out.println("Total amount of sales for each store : ");
        computeCost(items, cost);
        printArray(items, cost);
    }
    public static void loadArray(double items[][], double cost[])
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s1;
        int num, x, y;
        for(x=0; x<items.length;x++)
        {
            for(y=0; y<items[x].length; y++)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter the next item of data:");
                items[x][y]=input.nextDouble();
            }
        }

        //Cost of the items:
        cost[0]=12.00;
        cost[1]=17.95;
        cost[2]=95.00;
        cost[3]=86.50;
        cost[4]=78.00;
    }
    public static void printArray(double items[][], double cost[]) 
    {
        System.out.println("Number of items Sold During Day: ");
        int row, col;
        for (row =0;  row<items.length ; row++)
        {
            for(col=0; col<items[row].length; col++)
            {
                System.out.print( items[row][col]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("Cost Per Item: ");
        int i;
        for (i =0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(cost[i]);
        }
    }
    public static void computeCost (double items[][], double cost[])
    {
        int row, col;
        double productArray[]=new double[3];
        for (row =0;  row<items.length ; row++)
        {
            for(col=0; col<items[row].length; col++)
              {
                if(col==0)
                {
                    productArray[row]=items[row][col]*cost[0];
                    System.out.println(productArray[row]+" TEST1 ");
                }
                else if(col==1)
                {
                    productArray[row]=items[row][col]*cost[1];
                    System.out.println(productArray[row]+" TEST2 ");
                }
                else if(col==2)
                {
                    productArray[row]=items[row][col]*cost[2];
                    System.out.println(productArray[row]+" TEST3");
                }
                else if(col==3)
                {
                    productArray[row]=items[row][col]*cost[3];
                    System.out.println(productArray[row]+" TEST4 ");
                }
                else if(col==4)
                {
                    productArray[row]=items[row][col]*cost[4];
                    System.out.println(productArray[row]+" TEST5 ");
                }           
             }
        }
    }
}
```

The `computeCost()` method is where the multiplication takes place, however I'm wondering how I can store the values of the multiplication so that I can later add them up.

(For example the output of the `computeCost()` method first run is :

```
300.0 TEST1 
1148.8 TEST2 
2185.0 TEST3
3892.5 TEST4 
1092.0 TEST5
```

I would need a way to store those values and add them up, but since they're inside of the loops and if statements, I'm not sure of how to do that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please me more specific about the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually almost there already. What is going wrong is that you are overwriting the value at the index for a particular row at each new column. You should increment the value instead. It is also possible to use the same variable for each row (instead of an array), because you don't reuse the saved value in any way.

Also, it is not needed to create the if-else structure like you did for checking which column you are considering. You can generalize that part by using the value of the `col` variable instead.

The new `computeCost()` method would look like this:

```
public static void computeCost (double items[][], double cost[]) {
    for (int row = 0; row < items.length; row++) {
        double rowSum = 0.0;
        for(int col = 0; col < items[row].length; col++) {
            double colProduct = productArray[row] = items[row][col] * cost[col];
            rowSum += colProduct;
            System.out.println("Row: " + row + ", Col: " + col + ": " + colProduct);
        }

        System.out.println("Total row " + row + ": " + rowSum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, looking over this made me be able to understand how loops work with arrays a lot better by visualizing it.